# Is it possible for Firestore document Snapshot data to be undefined?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using typescript I get

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>.data(options?: SnapshotOptions | undefined): DocumentData
```

The question is.. Do I really have to check if data is possibly undefined

```
if (snapDoc.data()) //...
else //...
```

or it is safe to do `snapDoc.data()!` for the fact that the data can never be undefined?

**If it can be undefined then when or at what case does the data will return undefined?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are querying a single document using `getDoc(<DoucmentReference>)`  that returns a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot) then yes, `data()` will return `undefined` if that document does not exist.

```
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

If you are querying multiple documents using `getDocs(<query>)`, a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) is returned that has `.docs` property (array of [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querydocumentsnapshot)) that contains all matched documents that exist for sure. So `.data()` will never be `undefined` in that case as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

> If it can be undefined then when or at what case does the data will return undefined?

In short, `data()` can return `undefined` if you are using it on a `DocumentSnapshot` when you fetch a single document using `getDoc()`